# Add links in top tags on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, jobs

The new Top Percentile tags on Careers 2.0 are very nice.  (although I wouldn't have believed that I'm in the top 30% for iPhone)

They would be even nicer if they linked to the user's answers in that tag.

Comment: It would also be interesting to not stop at 'top 10%' and go for 3 or 1.

Comment: I agree, maybe 10 - 5 - 3 - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that this has been implemented.

Comment: Can you confirm this still works? Right now, they show up *unlinked* for me.